# Jinja2 to put a whole element in <option>

Tags: python, templates, flask, jinja2

I need to dynamically select from the following:

So that I can show the selected element depending on `POST` request.

I want to templatize `selected="selected"` so that I can choose where to put.

```
<select name="my_name">
    <option value="5min">5-Min</option>
    <option value="1hour" selected="selected">Hour</option>
    <option value="1day">Day</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I have *no idea* what you are asking here. You want to decide where to put the `selected` attribute based on the current value of `my_name`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume `target` is the desired value that you want to select (obtained from the POST dictionary).
Then you need two things:

Prepare a dictionary containing value - display text pairs for all options in the select, e.g

```
mydict = {'5min': '5-Min', '1hour': 'Hour', '1day': 'Day'}
```

In `yourtemplate.html`:

```
<select name="my_name">
    {% for key, value in mydict.items() %}
        <option value="{{key}}" 
        {% if (key == target) %} selected="selected" { %endif %}
        >
        {{value}}
        </option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

How to pass the `target` - in your view you need to do this (I assume you know the basics of views in Flask)

```
    target = request.form['key_of_the_data_we_need'] # the value that should be selected
    mydict = {'5min': '5-Min', '1hour': 'Hour', '1day': 'Day'} # helper for the select
    return render_template('yourtemplate.html', target=target, mydict=mydict)
```

This way, the data is sent to yourtemplate.html which contains the code discussed above, therefore selecting the desired `<select>` option.

Comment: I want to put `selected="selected` for only one element

Comment: The solution above should work fine. Can't test it now, but I've written a couple of those... You could do it without the value-display pairs, but then you have to write if statements for each option - which would lead to more messy code in my opinion.

Comment: How do you pass `target`?

Comment: I don't understand how to check the value of `target`. How do you pass `target`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60720/discussion-between-pawelp-and-epsilonsdfsdfdsf).

Answer (score 0):

Using the same approach as Pawel did, I just changed some small things in order to work with my actual version of Jinja2:

```
<select class="form-control" id="worker" name="worker">
     {% for key in workers %}
     <option value="{{key}}" {% if key == people.worker %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>
        {{key}}
     </option>
     {% endfor %}
</select>
```

And from the controller:

```
workers = {'First One','Second One', 'Third One'}
return render_template('edit.html', people=people, workers=workers)
```

Remember to put the controller code within the controller which is passing the data for the view.

Answer (score 0):

It is not totally clear to me what the background of your question is. If the reason is that you can't use `wtf.quick_form(yourform)` because you need some customization, you could simply use

```
{{ form.workers.__call__(**{'class': 'form-control'}) }}
```

for the respective field in your Jinja2 template. This selects the posted element in the form. Note how I define additional attributes (a class).

The result will be (for example):

```
<select class="form-control" id="worker" name="worker">
   <option value="0">text1</option>
   <option selected value="1">text2</option>
   <option value="2">text3</option>
</select>
```

This of course requires that you have a properly defined form:

```
class yourform(FlaskForm):
    workers = SelectField(
        'name',
        validators=[Required()],
        choices=[(0, 'text1'), (1, 'text2'), (2, 'text3')],
        coerce=int
    )
    (... whatever other fields here ...)
```